Do tenants renting a room in Spain have the right to letter box?
I've stayed in Spain (comunidad autonoma Catalonia) in rooms of three different owners booked via AirBnB, in each case for at least one month. I didn't have access to a letter box in any of those three places (in all of them the letter box was devastated and the landlords denied my requests of repairing them). Is it legal in Spain to let out residential property in Catalonia / Spain, without providing the tenants with the mailbox?
In what legal acts, statutes, or regulations could I read about it?

From what I can tell, Airbnb doesn't require their hosts to provide mailboxes for their guests, although host can do this on their option. An Airbnb is not a permanent residence, it's more like booking a hotel room.

And in the Airbnb community forum, the usual recommendation is to NOT allow guests to use your mailbox, as it's often used by scammers.

I think the OP is asking about legal requirements, rather than about AirBnB's rules.

Is poste restante a thing in Spain? Use that instead.

@Barmar There is nothing about the letter box among the services such as WiFi or washing machine that are listed for an accommodation. That said, AirBnB bills has been the basis of obtaining my empadronamiento and AirBnB as of now saves me being homeless.

@JonCuster There is something like that: https://www.correos.es/es/es/particulares/recibir/planifica-tus-entregas/apartado-postal I costs 38 euros per month. The addresses of such services are blacklisted by many financial institutions such as banks - and it is exactly from such institutions that I need to receive letters this year.

OK, can you rent a post office box (one at a post office), or one through a storefront (here in the US, both UPS and FedEx offices may have boxes to rent to have mail delivered to).

@JonCuster A post office box at a post office I can. But such office box is of limited use since banks want to know your actual abode - and would not send a debit card to the address of post office.

Well, the boxes at UPS (United Parcel Service - UPS, not the United States Postal Service - USPS) stores in the US come with a street address - the address of the store. They advertise it as an added benefit, perhaps because of issues like this. There are other services, often including available meeting space, but mostly are pitched towards business use, not personal.

I would say that the answer is no.
This page(in Spanish) mentions the Real Decreto 1829/1999 from december, 3rd (1999) about the rules for delivering post:

En aquellos inmuebles sujetos al régimen de propiedad horizontal se podrá hacer la entrega en los casilleros domiciliarios siempre que su número sea igual al de locales y viviendas susceptibles de aprovechamiento independiente, con otro más señalizado con el número 1 y reservado para las devoluciones de envíos postales.
Los casilleros domiciliarios deberán estar numerados, a partir del número 2, debiendo situarse correlativamente a contar de izquierda a derecha y de arriba abajo, ordenados por pisos y puertas. Estos datos se indicarán obligatoriamente en el casillero, pudiendo también figurar los nombres y apellidos de los residentes en la vivienda o la denominación social en caso de ser una persona jurídica el titular del local o vivienda. El bloque o bloques de casilleros domiciliarios se instalarán en un lugar de fácil acceso que esté bien iluminado y que tenga suficientes garantías de protección contra manipulaciones ilícitas, debiendo empotrarse o fijarse en la pared de modo que no puedan ser trasladados de lugar y estén colocados a una altura que permita su cómoda utilización. Si el operador al que se ha encomendado la prestación del servicio postal universal, o cualquier otro de los operadores postales, tuviesen conocimiento de la existencia de inmuebles que no dispusiesen de casilleros domiciliarios, se comunicará esta circunstancia a la comunidad de vecinos correspondiente, a fin de que tomen las medidas oportunas para su instalación, advirtiéndoles que, mientras tanto, la entrega de los envíos dirigidos a sus vecinos se realizará en la oficina postal que corresponda.

Basically, it says that letter box in an apartment building must be "the same number as dwellings and offices in the building, plus one (for returned mail)".
I would guess that the restriction of "the same number" is mostly to avoid two dwellings sharing a letter box (so, a letter to 1A goes to the 1A letter box, and not to a letter box to which the nosy neighbour from 1B has access), and probably nobody would sue a neighbour community because it has a letter box for "1A Juan Pérez" and another letter box for "1A John Smith".
That said, to install the additional letter box the owner would need permission for the community. Somewhat unlikely, specially for an AirBnb.
And it is to be seen if the postman would notice/care that there are several 1A letter boxes.
Incidentally, I live at a small apartment building and often there is nobody home when the postman comes. So, as the letter boxes are not accesible from the street, most of the time the postman just slips the mail under the street door and leaves it for us to sort, so it is not that individual letter boxes make much of a difference.

In most apartment buildings in the US, the letter boxes are outside the locked entrance door. If the building has a vestibule, the letter boxes are there. Otherwise, they're outside the building entirely. So the letter carrier doesn't need to slip under the door like that.

Is the AirBnB room a dwelling under Spanish law?

@Barmar in big cities such as New York the letter boxes are typically inside, but there is a mechanism to open the door using a standard USPS mailbox key -- the same key that the letter carrier uses to unlock outdoor letter boxes such as these to put the mail into them: https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-cluster-mailboxes-in-small-suburban-texas-city-neighborhood-84956043.html

@o.m. in respect to rights like privacy and intimacy, it is. The same than a hotel room. But it is not a different property. You could own a 25% of a home, but not "that room and that bathroom".
